# Creating a log with incrementing keys, without using a database

Tags: php, logging, file-io

I am currently creating for our company a web gui for viewing logs in an easy to view way. This system will support browsing and filtering log items and using a link to reach a certain log item.

My question is how should I design the key for each log item.

The environment I use does not, and will not, include a database. So I am using a file instead. In the best scenario each key should include these features:

- Unique (required)
- Incremental in a predictable pattern.
- Include a timestamp, to a granularity of minutes.

Using only a milisecond timestamp was the obvious solution, but then I will not have predictable incrementation, this will hurt performance.

Can you think of a way this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know there is a database system without a server, called SQLite. It is lightweight (350kb), client-only and usually already distributed with your favourite PHP package. That's why you probably will not need to install any new service to your server. However you still need to enable sqlite extension, if it is not.

Using sqlite is just like other classic database systems. However, it is optimized for local usage. In your scenario, I think using sqlite may simplify your design and programming.

Comment: Using SQlite would definitely make this project easy. I only need to make sure it is installed by default on the many servers on which our system is deployed. Main reason for not using mysql is the IT overhead needed to implement it on many servers.
Thanks a lot!